# How to enable creation of BizTalk-projects in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, biztalk

I have installed BizTalk Server 2010 and Visual Studio 2008. I have done that which is specified in this website: [Cannot create new BizTalk projects in Visual Studio 2008 – “Project Creation Failed”](http://masteringbiztalkserver.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/cannot-create-new-biztalk-projects-in-visual-studio-2008-project-creation-failed/#comment-31)

I can't find any option to create a BizTalk-project in Visual Studio 2008.
What should I do in order to enable this option?

Answer (score 1):

You need VS2010.

The BizTalk dev tools, up to this point, have only targeted a single version of VS. BTS2010/VS2010, BTS2009/VS2008, BTS06/VS2005.